# is a relation R total/linear/well-order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a relation on $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ i.e $\mathcal{R}\subseteq(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\times (\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})$ s.t $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(z,w)$ iff $x<z$ or $x=z \wedge y\le w$.

a)is $\mathcal{R}$ total order/linear order?

b) does the greatest and the smallest element exist?

c) is $\mathcal{R}$ a well order?

My solution

reflexivity:

$(x,y)\mathcal{R}(x,y)$ as $x=x$ and $y\le y$ $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$

antisymmetry

$(x,y)\mathcal{R}(y,x)$ as $x<y\vee x=y \wedge y\le x$ I am not sure about this one, I considered two examples:

$(1,2)\mathcal{R}(2,1)$  then $1<2$ so it is okay but

$(2,1)not\mathcal{R}(1,2)$ as $2\not< 1$ futhermore $2\neq 1$
so $\mathcal{R}$ is not antisymmetric? thus not total/linear order and not well-order?

Comment: You may wanted to write "y\leq y$ in the reflexivity part.

Comment: It *is* an order. Your example about antisymmetry says nothing. You have to prove "if $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(x',y')$ and $(x',y')\mathcal{R}(x,y)$, then $(x,y)=(x',y')$.

Comment: yes, I have fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that the relation is reflexive, and that's fine. But the others you haven't done right.$\newcommand{\R}{\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}}$

For antisymmetry, for example, you need to assume that $(x,y)\R(z,w)$ and $(z,w)\R(x,y)$. From that assumption you need to show that $(x,y)=(z,w)$. This condition needs to be shown *for every* $(x,y),(z,w)\in\Bbb{N\times N}$. One example is not enough!

You also have to show that this is a transitive relation. For the totality you also made a mistake. You have shown that there are two pairs such that $\R$ doesn't hold *in one direction*. But remember the definition of a total order:

> $(A,\preceq)$ is totally ordered if for every $a,b\in A$ it holds $a\preceq b$ or $b\preceq a$.

So the fact that $(2,1)\R(1,2)$ is false doesn't prove anything. You need to show that $(1,2)\R(2,1)$ is also false -- but you can't, because $(1,2)\R(2,1)$ is in fact true.

Finally, your title asks whether or not it is a total order, or a linear order, or a well-order. It is unclear whether or not you think that total and linear orders are different things; or that you think that linear orders and well-orders are the same thing. In either case it is wrong. All total orders are linear orders, and not all linear orders are well-orders.

Now, let me reveal you a little secret, this is indeed a well-order (so it is a total order as well). But I am going to leave you with the task of proving that.

Comment: Hello Asaf, thanks for clarifying, I am a beginner in this field.. so following your suggestions I have: assume $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(z,w)$ which means that either $x<z$ or $x=z$ and $y\le w$ and suppose that $(z,w)\mathcal{R}(x,y)$ then either $z<x$ or $z=x$ and $w\le y$ but we cannot have $x<z$ and $z<x$ thus we choose $x=z$ and $z=x$ and as $y\le w$ and $w\le y$ then $w=y$ so $(x,y)=(z,w)$ Right?

Comment: for the transitivity part. Suppose that $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(z,w)$ and $(z,w)\mathcal{R}(k,l)$. Then $x<z$ or $x=z$ and $y\le w$, by the second one $z<k$ or $z=k$ and $w\le l$ then $x<k$ or $x=k$ and $y\le l$ so $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(k,l)$ did I get this one right?

Comment: Yes, Heidi. That's good. Now you have shown that $\R$ is a partial order. It remains to show it is linear, and indeed a well-order (every non-empty set of has a minimal element).

Comment: I have difficult to understand the concept of linear order. I have to show that either $(x,y)\mathcal{R}(z,w)$ or $(z,w)\mathcal{R}(x,y)$ $\forall x,y,z,w\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ How to do that?

Comment: Heidi, assume that $(x,y)\R(z,w)$ fails. What could be the reason? Either $z<x$ or $z=x$ and $w\leq y$. Use this to show that $(z,w)\R(x,y)$ holds.

Comment: the condition you wrote above $z<x$ or $z=x$ and $w\le y$ (in particular $(x,y)not\mathcal{R} (z,w)$) is precisely what we need for $(z,w)\mathcal{R}(x,y)$ to hold, so what you have shown is that if $(x,y)not\mathcal{R} (z,w)$ then we must have $(z,w)\mathcal{R}(x,y)$ ?? is this the sense of the linear order? like for example in $\mathbb{N}$ with $\le$ we have $1\le 2$ but $2\not\le 1$

Comment: Yes. An order is linear if every two elements are comparable, so if one is not "smaller" than the other, it has to be "larger" (where smaller and larger refer to "appearing to the left/right" of the relation symbol, of course).

Comment: The relation is a linear order then. Is it a total order as well? the totality condition looks like the linearity condition to me...

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, total orders and linear orders are the same thing -- just two different names. Well-orders, however, are something else. It's a different requirement (which includes being a linear order, though).

Comment: How confusing! Yes, according to my book a set X is well-ordered by R if X is linearly ordered by R and every non empty subset of X contains a least element. We know that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered and a subset of a well ordered set is also well ordered. Can we consider $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, we can't. Because it's not true. You need to take $X$ to be a non-empty set of ordered pairs. Now let's try and find a minimal element in $X$. Consider the set $\{x\mid\exists y:(x,y)\in X\}$, the projection onto the left coordinate. It's a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$. Therefore it has a minimal element $x$, so if $X$ had a minimal element it would have to have $x$ as its left coordinate. But possibly $X$ has many ordered pairs with $x$ in their left coordinate, so we need to devise a way to pick one whose $y$ will guarantee us minimality with respect to $\R$. So we can do...?

Comment: hm...Now I am lost. I am not sure I understand your strategy here...

Comment: Heidi, suppose that $X$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{N\times N}$. We want to find an $\R$-minimal element in $X$. If $(x,y)$ is such $\R$-minimal, then whenever $(z,w)\in X$ we have to have that $x<z$ or $x=z$ and $y\leq w$. So I am trying to use the fact that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered in order to show that such element exists.